# Unable to deploy GCP Cloud Function after specifying IAM Condition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I have a client who has infrastructure on GCP. They are mostly serverless, running cloud functions, and have a set of existing functions which execute sensitive financial transactions, and that they don't want us to have access to. I've been trying to create a set of GCP permissions that allow my team to

- Edit, and deploy new functions, without having those permissions on the ones which they don't want us to have access to.
- Call only the new functions we create, but not the ones which they don't want us to have access to.

In AWS this would be simple. I'd just have them create a group and attach an IAM policy which specified the arns of the Lambdas we need access to, but it seems that I cannot do that in GCP.

So far, I have tried the following solutions (testing in our own cloud):

- I've added the Cloud Functions Developer role with an IAM condition that looks like this: `resource.name.startsWith("our-prefix")`. This worked almost perfectly, and we cannot edit or call their functions. We can call the ones we make, but unfortunately we cannot deploy them. When we try to deploy the cloud functions we have access to, we get the following error: `Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.generateUploadUrl' denied on projects/<our-project>/locations/<our-region>/functions`.
- I tried to add the full Cloud Functions Developer role, and then remove the rights to edit and invoke theirs by running `gcloud functions remove-invoker-policy-binding <args>` and `gcloud functions remove-iam-policy-binding <args>` but unfortunately that didn't work either.
- I tried adding the necessary permissions by hand, i.e. I tried to run `gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding <function> --member=<principal> --role=roles/cloudfunctions.developer` to only add specific roles to a user but this didn't work.

I've also made sure that every user has the roles `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`, Cloud Functions Developer is enabled in Cloud Run Settings, and have triple checked the necessary permissions for Cloud Functions to be deployable by a user (`roles/cloudfunctions.developer` and `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`). I really don't know why my first bulleted solution didn't work.

If anyone has a solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to create these new Cloud Functions in the same project as requirement? If the company has these kind of policies I would say that a workaround could be to create a project where you can work without these restrictions.

Comment: @ericcco That's probably what we're going to have to do. It's not super elegant ): I wish GCP had a better IAM implementation. This problem seems really basic to me (giving granular permissions to a subset of cloud functions). AWS solved it so long ago.

Answer (score 0):

'cloudfunctions.functions.generateUploadUr' means it can't upload code, as it doesn't get upload url.

I added permissions from cloudfunctions.functions.*

Some of them helped me. don't know wich particulary. Probaly one of:

- cloudfunctions.functions.sourceCodeGet
- cloudfunctions.functions.sourceCodeSet